# Lightning unsavedchanges for community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

*Posting this question after a lot of research and hit and trial using different events and ways.*

I am working on a lightning community that uses aura components and the whole application is a single page application where different components are being loaded based on user selection.

I am looking for a way to show a confirmation message to the user when they click on any other link outside of the component, which internally unloads the current component and loads another component so that users can click on **Ok** or **Cancel**

**lightning:unsavedChanges** - After a lot of struggle, realized that it is not supported in lightning community, not sure why limitation!!

**unrender** - when flow reaches to unrender method, it is very late to stop component destruction. Not possible

**window.beforeunload** - tried and didn't work and the function didn't get executed.

Please share custom code which can be used.  
 *Note: I can use HTML default confirm notification window.*